# Update WP Media Library image unattended

Tags: media-library

I have a restaurant website that is in Joomla that I want to redo in WP. The user takes a picture of their new menu item with their smartphone and after answering a couple of questions (which enables me to determine the filename), they press enter and upload the image to the server. This image becomes the current image on the website. This image replaces or updates existing image pages. Of course, replacing images in the Uploads folder doesn't work with WP without manual intervention. My question is, how can I update the WP Media Library without manual intervention?

Comment: Are the url of attachment image from your old site?
share your website link

Comment: Here is the old site - (https://www.northcountrysteakbuffet.com/menu/dinner/tuesday-dinner.html). The 3 images shown here will be imported using Media Library. It's the future images that will replace these that I'm asking about.

Comment: Here's the new link (https://ncsb-lax.com/monday-dinner/)  These images need to be updated without manual intervention. It appears that the only way I can do this is with a WP function. What I've seen so far is POST functions but there is no data input form here only server file processing.